# Angular 5 growing browser memory

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom, single-page-application

I have Angular 5 project. It's admin web with many tabs. Every tab contains complicated filter and grid. After often switching tabs grows memory (in Chrome js heap size), but number of DOM Nodes isn't growing. It's not problem to grow memory to 1GB in 5 minutes. IE has a limit of about 1.5 GB and then falls due to a lack of memory.

At first I thought it was only a problem of our application or Angular, but I created a simple html test page with two buttons and simple javascript. One button adds a textbox and the other removes it. Then I created a simple E2E test that added 1000 times and removed the textbox and memory in the browser grew as well. Tested in Chrome (66) and IE11 with same symptoms as angular application, JS Heap is increasing, but number of DOM Nodes is fine.

Then I tried to watch for example facebook.com, that is one of best known single page application. I watched the same behavior and it is not a problem to drop the app in a moment.

I think this problem is caused by adding and removing many html elements over and over again.

Does anyone have similar experiences or solution?

Comment: If you're using a navigation controller you need to see that your pages are disposed properly. I came across an issue the other day where the old pages were still left in the dom after navigating away.

Comment: have you subscribe to ngDestory and avoided memeory leaks by disposing things

Comment: Javascript is not only the DOM nodes.  One possible approach is to do memory snapshots in chrome dev tools. Try to identify if there are memory blocks that should not be there and identify any retainers that prevent memory from being freed. My personal experience - I was surprised once to find out that console.log( obj )  would actually prevent that obj from being released.

Comment: btw, one more thing to note. Application/Page MAY grow in memory and consume all the memory given to it. What you are interested in is - which of that memory will be garbage-collected once GC kicks in. And you dont know exactly when that moment happens.